# Save view in blender 2.8

Tags: interface

Is there any way to save the view that is not front, back, top, etc.?
I am in edit mode and select surface then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>. It takes me to the view looking straight onto that surface.
I can then use then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to rotate that view. Now I want to save it.
Is there any way without using the camera?

Comment: The Stored Views addon hasn't been updated for 2.80 yet. Soooo...no.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that.

Comment: Looks like no one is planning to update the stored views addon, it has been [moved to addons_contrib](https://developer.blender.org/rBAd9ffde707fe559f2cbfefb39b75f4decb42aa0a1).

Comment: Does it mean that it will never be in version 2.80?

Comment: Unless someone fixes it right now, it won't be part of the 2.80 release. That doesn't mean it will never get updated and come back in a later release. [Francesco](https://www.fsiddi.com) is credited in the addon and may know if there are any plans for it. You could also suggest updating it at [Right Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/) to see if someone else wants to work on it.

Comment: Work has [been done](https://developer.blender.org/rBAC1b2015236d9a) to update stored views. Not sure if it will get into the release but if you download the [contrib repo](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender-addons-contrib.git/snapshot/master.tar.gz) you can copy the `space_view3d_stored_views` folder into your addons folder.